# text view not handling hebrew + roman characters in same string

Tags: android, unicode, localization, textview, hebrew

When using a textview to display a string from my values XML it parses them in an odd way from what I've seen to be my standard. It seems to seperate my string into chunks of hebrew and roman/punctuation. Each chunk is handled properly (RTL/LTR) but the chunks overall are parsed left to right rather than right to left.

Example: (arrows denote LTR/RTL)

My XML string (how it should be displayed):
     [hebrew (C) <<<<] [english word  (B)>>>>] [hebrew (A) <<<<]

How it is displayed on android:
     [hebrew (A) <<<<] [english word  (B)>>>>] [hebrew (C) <<<<]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. :)

Edit: Turns out when I open my XML in eclipse it displays it in the same *incorrect* way (second case) but most text editors display it correctly (first case)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62099816/878126

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.0 offers much better support of BiDi text. Give it a try with the emulator and see if it fixes your problem.